# ASP.Net ASMX Webservice in Class Library (Best Practice)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

i have a best practice question. I'm working on an Vb.net Webproject in Visual Studio. We are creating some modules that are defined in its own Class Library Project Folders. I want to bundle all files for this module within the project folder ... that include the WebServices.

I tried to define a WebService as in this HowTo described (http://www.dotnetwire.com/Articles/Class_Library_Project.asp) but i can't reach the WebService (404). Is this approach obsolete with IIS 7.5 or higher cause i found some postings on codeproject where other users have similar problems.

Is there a better way to "outsource" a webservice to its own library since when the upper HowTo was written ?

Greetings and thx in advance for help.

M. Lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general trend nowadays is to migrate away from the old .asmx services and toward REST.  If you're using .NET the standard has been more and more ASP.NET Web API.  Having said that, I develop my REST services in completely different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the info i expected that i should use REST. Is there any good HowTo for build REST API from scratch ? I didn't find one.